# how to style the particular input type element without affect the others

Tags: css, input-type-file

I have a problem in selecting the particular input file element in html using selector.

How to style the particular input type element without affect the others

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you already read?

Comment: can you post a snippet of the code?

Comment: Show us your code and go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can style a particular type of input element in below was 
1) Apply a class or id to the input element and write styles for that class or id

**HTML**

```
<input class="custom-file" type="file"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-file {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

2)Or You can target the input type itself in genral like the below snippet.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="file"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This will apply the css only for the input type file, and not for other input types such as text etc. This will add border red to all the input tags in the page with type file.

3) Or if more than one input file is present try targetting using the nth-child selector in css

```
**HTML**

 <input class="custom-file" type="file"/>
 <input class="custom-file" type="file"/>
 <input class="custom-file" type="file"/>

**CSS:** 
input[type="file"]:nth-child(2) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This will add border only to the second instance of the input type file.

Comment: if there is an two <input type="file"/> how can gave style for one. That is my question

Comment: add a class to that input file and style it.